# refresh the variable with date django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Need your's help, i have django project and javascript variable what take date from django now_date.
But for me need, the value of date must refresh every minute, so how i can do this? please help.

there is variable :

```
var aaa = '{{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}'
var aaa2 = '{{ now_date_plus1m|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}'
```

and this is using :

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
        .datetimepicker({value:aaa,step:10});
```

P.S. (innerHTML or something else, doesn't work for this field jquery)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
    .datetimepicker({value:new Date({{ now_date.year }}, {{ now_date.month }}, {{ now_date.day }}), step:10});
```